# Removing absolute value from argument of logarithm in $\frac{(x)^{1/3}\log|x+1|}{e^x-1}$ to find asymptotic

Tags: calculus

I want to find the asymptotics of the following function when $x\rightarrow0$. This is what my textbook does:

$$\frac{(x)^{1/3}\log|x+1|}{e^x-1}=\frac{(x)^{1/3}\log(x+1)}{e^x-1}=\dots$$

I wonder why my textbook removes the absolute value? Is it because the argument of a logarithm must be positive? Any hints?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For $x$ "near" $0$ we have $x+1$ "near" $1$, hence in the considerations concerning $x \to 0$, we can assume that $x+1>0$.

Answer (score 2):

The logarithm is defined only when it's argument is positive. When you have an absolute value as the argument of the logarithm the latter is defined $\forall x$ and is positive as $x$ approaches zero because you have $x+1$ as the argument.

If there wasn't that $+1$ and your function was something like this $$f(x)=\frac{x^{1\over3}\log|x|}{e^x-1}$$ then you have to split the limit as$x$ goes to zero in two parts, mainly $$\lim\limits_{x\rightarrow 0^+}\frac{x^{1\over3}\log(x)}{e^x-1}\\\lim\limits_{x\rightarrow 0^-}\frac{x^{1\over3}\log(-x)}{e^x-1}$$